# Home View in UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, uiview, uitabbarcontroller

I have a starter UIView and if user clicks the button in starter view present a tabbar model view. In that view, I have a tab bar controller with 4 items as the first one "Home" tabbar item where if user clicks it dismisses the tabbar controller view and go back to the start view (so when tabbar view is loaded it starts with the second tabbar item). My question is: how can I dismiss the tabbar controller when user clicks the home tabbar item.

Answer (score 0):

Ehm I think this is against guidelines and would advice you to try a different approach. However, you could make the home button load a view which class has `[self presentModalViewController:starterViewController animated:NO];` in `viewWillAppear`